# Ingest 2-digit year with druid?

Tags: jodatime, druid

I want to ingest dates of the format MM/dd/yy (e.g. 02/01/03 for Feb 1 2003).  I can't figure out how to specify this using a joda time format string, which seems to be what druid requires.

In java code I can do this by specifying a pivot year for the joda DateTimeFormatter, but there seems to be no way to do this with just a format string (which is all that is available in the druid ingest spec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of trial-and-error and discovered the following, which I still cannot find documented anywhere.

- The 'pivot' for two-digit years is 40.  Years above 40 are in the 1900s, and years below 40 are in the 2000s.  This means that:

  - 3/4/97 is March 4th, 1997
  - 3/4/04 is March 4th, 2004
  - 3/4/40 is March 4th, 2040
  - 3/4/41 is March 4th, 1941
- Do not specify a one-digit year!  This will not work as you expect; for example:

  - 3/4/3 is March 4th in the year 3 AD.  You must specify '03' if you mean 2003.
- Do not specify a one-y format string! For example, the format string "M/d/y" when applied to "3/4/03" will be interpreted as March 4 in the year 3 AD.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in the timestampSpec how your timestamp should be parsed.

For example:

```
"timestampSpec": {
  "column": "timestamp",
  "format": "MM/dd/yy"
}
```

See also this page: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html#timestampspec